# SpecFlow Step - view all

Tags: c#, specflow

I am creating a specflow suite of tests. I want it such that non technical testers can write tests in english by only writing feature files. I have done all the step definitions.

However, how does a tester know that a step is already created to do what he wants. There should be a view of all steps and from which feature file they are used to help a novice tester to use the suite.

Is this functionality in SpecFlow?

Writing a step name, and hoping intellisense will pick it up is not the functionality that I want, as this wont work for my purpses.

Please let me know. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all steps by creating **Step Definition Report**:

```
specflow.exe stepdefinitionreport MyProj.csproj /out:MySteps.html
```

See: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Reporting